# Include Mongodb "_id" field in projection with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am retrieving a Mongo document using Node.js and Mongoose like this:

```
var app = express();
var Thread = mongoose.model('threads', schema);
app.get('/api/closed/all', function(req, res) {
    Thread.find({ IsCLOSED: true }, function(err, post){
        res.send(post);
    });
});
```

But it's not returning the "_id" field, what am I missing?

In the documentation it says that by default _id should be included

Thanks

** Edit **

Solution: I had to specify it in the Schema:

var schema = new mongoose.Schema( {_id : String ........ } );

Comment: Your code is correct , how you know _id is missing . Will you iterate response object and display output in question.?

Comment: When looking at the answer in the endpoint, _id is not present, all the other fields are

Comment: how you have created _id , its manually created ids or mongo had created Object ID for you ?

Comment: it's manually created

Comment: I found out why it is, I have to specify it in the Mongoose Schema:

`var schema = new mongoose.Schema( {_id : String .... } );`

regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If  manually created, `_id` is not and `Object`.  By default, mongoose assumes that `_id` is an `ObjectId`.  If you want to be able to get the manually created IDs, you need to specify that in your schema.

If `_id`  is a `Number` then you have to explicitly specify in schema.

```
schema= new Schema({
            _id: Number
        }),

var Thread = mongoose.model('threads', schema);
```